# Ext.Msg.alert and Ext.Msg.show not showing "message" field

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.2

Im using `Ext.Msg.alert()` and 'Ext.Msg.show()' to show my message box. But so far only the Title is displayed with an OK button, but the message field is not shown. There's no error when I run the code. Anything that I miss?

Below is my code when using `Ext.Msg.alert()`,

```
Ext.Msg.alert('Title', 'Why you no display!?', Ext.emptyFn);
```

and when using `Ext.Msg.Show()`,

```
Ext.Msg.show({
    title:'Title', 
    message: 'Why you no display!?',
    buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK, 
    fn:Ext.emptyFn
});
```

**Update on 27th August 2013**

I found that the message box works when running on IOS Devices, but not on Android and on Desktop Browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging trough the web, I finally found the solution. It turns out the fix is in the sass file in base folder.

The original post is [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?269123-2.2.1-default-app.css-amp-chromium-blink-problem&p=987612&viewfull=1#post987612).

In short,

Go to `touch\resources\themes\stylesheets\sencha-touch\base\mixins`, open the `_Class.scss` file and replace the whole block of `@mixin st-box` with the code below, and then re-compile your css (e.g. use compass watch)

```
@mixin st-box($important: no) {
    @if $important == important {
        display: flex !important;
        display: -webkit-box !important;
        display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    } @else {
        display: flex;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
    }
}
```